# $X\subset Y \implies \overline{X}\subset \overline{Y}$ (closure inclusion subset)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that $X,Y\subset M$, being $M$ a metric space.

In order to prove that:

$$X\subset Y \implies \overline{X}\subset \overline{Y}$$

If $x\in \overline{X}$ we have that $d(x,X) = 0$. But I cannot see how it implies that $d(x,Y) = 0$. I know that $x\in X \implies x\in Y$, but I need to show that $x\in \overline{X}\implies x\in \overline Y$ and I can't see any relations.

I could also use the definition that

$x\in \overline{X}\implies \exists A | A\cap X\neq \emptyset$ where $x\in A$. Maybe there is some property of inclusion relating intersections?

Any ideas? Thanks <3

Comment: Do you know that these are metric spaces? If not, you may have to rely on the definition of closure.

Comment: @NicholasStull yes, sorry, they are metric spaces

Comment: The answer is pretty immediate when considering the definition of closure from a topological point of view.  $\overline{A}=\bigcap\mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{F} = \{F~:~\text{closed}~F\supseteq A\}$.  Notice that $X\subseteq Y$ you have $\mathcal{F}_x \supseteq \mathcal{F}_y$.  It wasn't mentioned that there was a topology explicitly, but one could use the topology induced from the metric.  It would remain to show that the two definitions of closure are equivalent in that case.

Comment: I wasn't sure if we were using metric spaces (the only reason I asked is the reference to $d(x,X)$). But the much faster way to approach this is to use the definition of closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X \subset Y$. Let $x \in cl(X) \setminus cl(Y)$. Then there exists $V_x$ with $V_x \cap Y = \emptyset$ which is a contradiction since $X \subset Y$.

Comment: what's $V_x$? An open set containing $x$?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: Yes.

Comment: I can't understand the contradiction. Could you help me?

Comment: $X \subset Y$ so there is no way you can take an open set about $x$ and have trivial intersection with $Y$, at the least, the intersection contains $x$.

Answer (score 3):

$x \in \overline{X}$ iff for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$, $U \cap X \neq \emptyset$. But $U \cap X \neq \emptyset \implies U \cap Y \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: (the last line follows from $U\cap X \subset U\cap Y$, in case OP wants clarification) This is exactly what I was typing up, but you were faster.

Answer (score 0):

In metric spaces, one definition of closure is the original set plus all its limit points. Then clearly closure preserves the subset relation.